# Scheduling a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a powershell script that I want to run as a schedule job.

The script runs great when I execute it manually, but when I run the schedule task, the job fails with the message "could not start"

Schedule job setup:

Run:      powershell -command "& 'ScriptName.ps1'"
Start in: 
Run as:

This is scheduled on a Windows Server 2003 and is running powershell 1.

Comment: what is the ampersand for?  When I want to debug these, I configure the job to interact with the desktop and start a cmd shell.  From there I run the command-line and fix things until it works.  The idea being that you can sure permissions and config issues interactively first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. try to use the full path of ScriptName.ps1
2. does the script depend on anything in your $Profile? if it does, it may not be loaded when you run as a schedule job, so make sure that you load the module or set up env variables needed.

Comment: when I tried using the full path, same error.

Comment: I ended up needing to use the full path fro both the script and powershell itself. Apparently powershell wasn't in PATH

Comment: @Scott can you please explain bit more in detail what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to including the full path for powershell.exe and the full path for the script in the "Run" textbox:
`C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "C:\FULLPATH\MYSCRIPT.ps1"`